# How to change the position of an image?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to position the the crust to stay in the middle even with the different sizes. But it seems to go lower as i change the size of the crust. I tried adding style to the crust but it doesn't seem to stay. i will also create a js fiddle to show everything: 
https://jsfiddle.net/x893h72p/11/

The images on the js fiddle are bigger than the ones i have but I didn't know how to link my actual images. Is that okay?

Thank you.

Here is my hmtl:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Pietro's Pizza</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body class="bodyDiv">

        <header class="headerBox" id="top">
            <img src="images/logo.png" width=250px height=250px>
        </header>

        <article>
            <form>
                <div class="bannerBox">
                    <div class="bannerColumn center">
                        <select id="sizeId" size="1" name="pizza_size" class="pizzaSize">
                            <option data-name="title" selected disabled>Select Pizza Size:</option>
                            <option value="4" data-name="Extra Large Pizza" data-price="12.50">Extra Large</option>
                            <option value="3" data-name="Large Pizza" data-price="10.00">Large</option>
                            <option value="2" data-name="Medium Pizza" data-price="7.50">Medium</option>
                            <option value="1" data-name="Small Pizza" data-price="5.00">Small</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="bannerColumn2 center noRightMargin">
                        <select id="crustId" size="1" name="crust_type" class="pizzaCrust">
                            <option data-name="title" selected disabled>Select Crust Type:</option>
                            <option value="1" data-name="Cracker Crust" data-price="0.25">Cracker</option>
                            <option value="2" data-name="Thin Crust" data-price="0.50">Thin</option>
                            <option value="3" data-name="Regular Crust" data-price="0.00">Regular</option>
                            <option value="4" data-name="Thick Crust" data-price="1.00">Thick</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="threeTextBox">
                    <div class="textColumn1 hidden" id="toppingsId" >
                        <b>Select Toppings:</b><br>
                        <p>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="extra_cheese_box" id="extraCheeseBox"
                                value ="1" data-label-id="extraCheeseLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".25" data-name="Extra Cheese"
                                data-image="images/04extracheese.png" data-layer="4">
                                <label for="extraCheeseBox" id="extraCheeseLebel"><span><span></span></span>Extra Cheese</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="pepperoni_box" id="pepperoniBox" 
                                value ="2" data-label-id="pepperoniLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".50" data-name="Pepperoni" 
                                data-image="images/05pepperoni.png" data-layer="5">
                                <label for="pepperoniBox" id="pepperoniLebel"><span><span></span></span>Pepperoni</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="ham_box" id="hamBox" 
                                value ="3" data-label-id="hamLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".75" data-name="Ham" 
                                data-image="images/06ham.png" data-layer="6">
                                <label for="hamBox" id="hamLebel"><span><span></span></span>Ham</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="bacon_box" id="baconBox" 
                                value ="4" data-label-id="baconLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price="1.00" data-name="Bacon" 
                                data-image="images/07bacon.png" data-layer="7">
                                <label for="baconBox" id="baconLebel"><span><span></span></span>Bacon</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="beef_box" id="beefBox" 
                                value ="5" data-label-id="beefLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".75" data-name="Beef" 
                                data-image="images/08beef.png" data-layer="8">
                                <label for="beefBox" id="beefLebel"><span><span></span></span>Beef</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="shrimp_box" id="shrimpBox" 
                                value ="6" data-label-id="shrimpLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price="1.50" data-name="Shrimp" 
                                data-image="images/09shrimp.png" data-layer="9">
                                <label for="shrimpBox" id="shrimpLebel"><span><span></span></span>Shrimp</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="anchovy_box" id="anchovyBox" 
                                value ="7" data-label-id="anchovyLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price="1.00" data-name="Anchovy"
                                data-image="images/10anchovy.png" data-layer="10">
                                <label for="anchovyBox" id="anchovyLebel"><span><span></span></span>Anchovy</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="tomato_box" id="tomatoBox" 
                                value ="8" data-label-id="tomatoLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".20" data-name="Tomato"
                                data-image="images/11tomato.png" data-layer="11">
                                <label for="tomatoBox" id="tomatoLebel"><span><span></span></span>Tomato</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="mushrooms_box" id="mushroomsBox" 
                                value ="9" data-label-id="mushroomsLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".30" data-name="Mushrooms"
                                data-image="images/12mushrooms.png" data-layer="12">
                                <label for="mushroomsBox" id="mushroomsLebel"><span><span></span></span>Mushrooms</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="green_peppers_box" id="greenPeppersBox" 
                                value ="10" data-label-id="greenPeppersLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".25" data-name="Green Peppers"
                                data-image="images/13greenpeppers.png" data-layer="13">
                                <label for="greenPeppersBox" id="greenPeppersLebel"><span><span></span></span>Green Peppers</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="black_olives_box" id="blackOlivesBox" 
                                value ="11" data-label-id="blackOlivesLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".45" data-name="Black Olives"
                                data-image="images/14blackolives.png" data-layer="14">
                                <label for="blackOlivesBox" id="blackOlivesLebel"><span><span></span></span>Black Olives</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="green_olives_box" id="greenOlivesBox" 
                                value ="12" data-label-id="greenOlivesLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".40" data-name="Green Olives"
                                data-image="images/15greenolives.png" data-layer="15">
                                <label for="greenOlivesBox" id="greenOlivesLebel"><span><span></span></span>Green Olives</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="onion_box" id="onionBox" 
                                value ="13" data-label-id="onionLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".15" data-name="Onion"
                                data-image="images/16onion.png" data-layer="16">
                                <label for="onionBox" id="onionLebel"><span><span></span></span>Onion</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="pineapple_box" id="pineappleBox" 
                                value ="14" data-label-id="pineappleLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".65" data-name="Pinapple"
                                data-image="images/17pineapple.png" data-layer="17">
                                <label for="pineappleBox" id="pineapppleLebel"><span><span></span></span>Pineapple</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="hot_banana_peppers_box" id="hotBananaPeppersBox" 
                                value ="15" data-label-id="hotBananaPeppersLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".65" data-name="Hot Banana Peppers"
                                data-image="images/18hotbananapeppers.png" data-layer="18">
                                <label for="hotBananaPeppersBox" id="hotBananaPeppersLebel"><span><span></span></span>Hot Banana Peppers</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="jalapeno_peppers_box" id="jalapenoPeppersBox" 
                                value ="16" data-label-id="jalapenoPeppersLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".85" data-name="Jalapeno Peppers"
                                data-image="images/19jalapenopeppers.png" data-layer="19">
                                <label for="jalapenoPeppersBox" id="jalapenoPeppersLebel"><span><span></span></span>Jalapeno Peppers</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="basil_box" id="basilBox" 
                                value ="17" data-label-id="basilLabel" class="pizzaTopping"
                                data-price=".15" data-name="Basil"
                                data-image="images/20basil.png" data-layer="20">
                                <label for="basilBox" id="basilLebel"><span><span></span></span>Basil</label><br>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="textColumn2" id="pizzaImage">
<img id="layer1" src="images/01crust.png" class="hidden" style=" position: absolute; top: 350px; ">
                        <img id="layer2" src="images/02sauce.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer3" src="images/03cheese.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer4" src="images/04extracheese.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer5" src="images/05pepperoni.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer6" src="images/06ham.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer7" src="images/07bacon.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer8" src="images/08beef.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer9" src="images/09shrimp.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer10" src="images/10anchovy.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer11" src="images/11tomato.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer12" src="images/12mushrooms.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer13" src="images/13greenpeppers.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer14" src="images/14blackolives.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer15" src="images/15greenolives.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer16" src="images/16onion.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer17" src="images/17pineapple.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer18" src="images/18hotbananapeppers.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer19" src="images/19jalapenopeppers.png" class="hidden">
                        <img id="layer20" src="images/20basil.png" class="hidden">
                    </div>

                    <div class="textColumn3 center noRightMargin">
                        <div class="itemDiv hidden" id="toppingItem">
                            <b>Pizza Items:</b><br>
                        </div>

                        <div class="priceDiv hidden" id="toppingPrice">
                            <b>&nbsp;</b><br>
                        </div>

                        <div class="orderBtnBox hidden" id="orderBtn">
                            <input type="submit" class="button round center" id="orderBtn" value="Place Order">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </article>

            <footer class="threeFooterBox">
                <div class="footerColumn">
                    <h3>
                        Links:
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#top">Home</a><br>
                        <a href="#">Menu</a><br>
                        <a href="#">Catering</a><br>
                        <a href="#contactInfo">Contact Us</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="footerColumnTable">
                    <h3 class="center">
                        Hours:
                    </h3>
                    <table width="280" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" class="hoursTable">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr align="left" valign="top">
                                <td>Sunday - Thursday</td>
                                <td>11:00 am - 10:00pm</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr align="left" valign="top">
                                <td>Friday - Saturday</td>
                                <td>11:00am - 11:00pm</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="footerColumn" id="contactInfo">
                    <h3>
                        Contact Us:
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        123 Main Street<br>
                        Ourtown, Ontario<br>
                        L1A 2B3
                    </p><p>
                        905 434 9191<br>
                        <a href="mailto:pietro@pizza.com" target="_top">pietro@pizza.com</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="footerColumnImage">
                    <img src="images/logo_black.jpg">
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div> <!-- end .container -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The images on the js fiddle are bigger than the ones i have -- if you want the image to be same size search on google e.g (300x300 jpg)

Answer (score 0):

well there is some trick i use, you might find it helpful..

```
img {
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```

the following will center the image to it's relative container.